# EasyNetQ subscribe throws taskCanceledException

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

I'm trying to create a basic example of rabitMQ messaging using EasynetQ lib in C#.
when I do this on localhost it is working fine, but when I try to connect to a rabbitmq server on a different machine, I get a Taskcanceled exception when calling the subscribe metod.
I'm using .net 7.0 with easynetQ 7.5.5
here is my publisher code:

```
using EasyNetQ;
using RabbitMQLearning.Shared.Messages;

var counter = 0;
using var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=webdev;port=5672;username=usr;password=pwd");

var Timer = new Timer(PublishMessage, state:null,dueTime:0,period: (int) new TimeSpan(0,0,1).TotalMilliseconds);

await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite);


void PublishMessage(object state)
{

    var message = new BasicMessage {
        Id= counter,
        Text = $"Hello {counter} from the rabbit hole"
    };

    bus.PubSub.Publish(message);

    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff")} Message {counter} sent");
    counter++;
}
```

the subscriber:

```
using EasyNetQ;
using RabbitMQLearning.Shared.Messages;

using var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=webdev;port=5672;username=usr;password=pwdx");

bus.PubSub.Subscribe<BasicMessage>("MadHatter", SubscribeMessage);
Console.WriteLine("subscribed");

await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite);

Task SubscribeMessage(BasicMessage message) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff")} {message.Id} heard");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

and the message object:

```
namespace RabbitMQLearning.Shared.Messages {
    public class BasicMessage {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After a few seconds I get a TaskCanceledException on the `subscribe<BasicMessage>` call.
the subscribem consolemessage was not hit at all

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it was a silly bannapeel, it was not able to resolve the server name in the connection string. if I use an FQDN or an IP address in the host part, then it's works just fine.